# TropFishR plot.lfq function limiting, how to produce a similar graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a time series for fisheries length-frequency data, using the TropFishR package, which is great but it does not offer much option for customising the actual plot.

For example, I would like to look at the data in fortnightly periods, the default of the function is to aggregate by month, I manually aggregated my data to the periods required as suggested by the R documentation of the package; however, once everything is plotted the labels on the ticks of the axis only show for one of the periods, not both.

The the label for the first period 01-Feb; 01-Mar etc is displayed for each month, but the second period 15-Feb; 15-Mar isn't. Like so:

[image: image 1]

I would also like to standardise the y-axis, as I will have about four of these graphs and the lengths are different (males and females). My attempts to do that with ylim have failed as the following is produced:

[image: image 2]

The transformations by this package produce lists, this is the code I am currently using:

```
require(TropFishR)
data$Period<-as.Date(data$Period)
LF_graph <- lfqCreate(data, Lname = "Length", Dname = "Period",
                     aggregate_dates = FALSE, species="hake",
                     length_unit = "cm", bin_size = 1, plot=FALSE)


lw<-lfqModify(LF_graph, bin_size=1)
lw_f<-lfqRestructure(lw,MA=3,addl.sqrt = FALSE)
prop.table(lw_f$catch, margin=2)*100
lw_f$catch<-prop.table(lw_f$catch, margin=2)*100

plot(lw_f, Fname = "catch", date.axis = "modern", date.format="%d-%b",
                 ylim=c(10,35), xlim=range(lw_f$dates)+c(-15,+15),
hist.sc=0.95, image.col=NA, ylab="Length classes (cm)")
```

This is the output, I called `dput((head(lw_f,5))` because I was afraid that 20 would be too long

```
list(species = "hake", stock = NA, dates = structure(c(17928, 
17942, 17956, 17970, 17987, 18001, 18017), class = "Date"), midLengths = c(8.5, 
9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 
20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5), catch = structure(c(0.104712041884817, 
0.104712041884817, 0.942408376963351, 2.19895287958115, 4.18848167539267, 
3.87434554973822, 2.72251308900524, 1.8848167539267, 1.04712041884817, 
0.628272251308901, 0.104712041884817, 0.209424083769634, 1.04712041884817, 
7.32984293193717, 19.8952879581152, 27.0157068062827, 18.5340314136126, 
7.12041884816754, 0.837696335078534, 0.104712041884817, 0.104712041884817, 
0, 0.117096018735363, 0.117096018735363, 0, 0.234192037470726, 
0.936768149882904, 1.63934426229508, 1.87353629976581, 1.28805620608899, 
1.28805620608899, 0.117096018735363, 0, 0.468384074941452, 5.62060889929742, 
20.1405152224824, 36.4168618266979, 21.7798594847775, 7.02576112412178, 
0.936768149882904, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.06382978723404, 6.38297872340426, 
8.51063829787234, 10.6382978723404, 22.3404255319149, 8.51063829787234, 
12.7659574468085, 11.7021276595745, 6.38297872340426, 2.12765957446809, 
3.19148936170213, 0, 0, 4.25531914893617, 2.12765957446809, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.162337662337662, 0.162337662337662, 1.46103896103896, 
1.78571428571429, 4.22077922077922, 6.00649350649351, 8.6038961038961, 
11.6883116883117, 10.5519480519481, 8.44155844155844, 6.49350649350649, 
1.2987012987013, 0.649350649350649, 0.162337662337662, 1.13636363636364, 
7.95454545454545, 16.3961038961039, 8.92857142857143, 2.92207792207792, 
0.974025974025974, 0, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 8, 24, 20, 8, 12, 
8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 66.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.76190476190476, 9.52380952380952, 
4.76190476190476, 4.76190476190476, 4.76190476190476, 14.2857142857143, 
23.8095238095238, 28.5714285714286, 4.76190476190476), .Dim = c(21L, 
7L)))
```

I have been unable to find a way to get this level of customisation with the TropFishR package, is there a way to reproduce this graph using another package, say ggplot2, but maybe using the transformed data from the TropFishR package?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks very doable in ggplot. I'd either use `geom_rect` or make facets for each fortnight and use `geom_col` plus `coord_flip`.  Can you share the output of `dput(lw_f)` in the text of your question (or `dput(head(lw_f,20))` if it's too much) so we can have a better idea what your data looks like?

Comment: Thank you! I've added the output, I am a bit unsure how to use lists in conjunction with ggplot2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by entierly circumventing the TropFishR package, I calculated the length-frequency using the code from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57463204/how-to-vectorize-length-frequency-calculation) wapping it in a function and running it through dlply to get LF tables for each time period, which can be easily converted to a data frame and plotted with geom_bar in whatever style is desired.